# Cartesian product of two lists as parameters for a command

Tags: parsing

Friends, I used to suffer a lot when had to iterate through elements of a list, but thanks to egreg's suggestion, I've been successfully using the `etoolbox` package for that task, e.g.:

```
\DeclareListParser*{\dothedance}{;}
\dothedance{\fbox}{item1; item2; item3}
```

Now, I'm trying to get all the pairs of a cartesian product of two lists (pardon the following Haskell code):

```
Prelude> [ (x,y) | x <- ['A','B','C'], y <- ['a','b','c','d'] ]
[('A','a'),('A','b'),('A','c'),('A','d'),('B','a'),('B','b'),('B','c'),('B','d'),('C','a'),('C','b'),('C','c'),('C','d')]
```

Then, for each pair, I'd like to break it into two parameters (*x* and *y*) and pass them to a command.

For example, consider two lists `[Hello, Howdy]` and `[Ann, Mary, Kate]` and the following dummy command:

```
\newcommand\saysomething[2]{#1~#2}
```

I'd expect each pair to be the parameters of that command. So the output would be:

```
Hello Ann
Hello Mary
Hello Kate
Howdy Ann
Howdy Mary
Howdy Kate
```

I'm pretty sure `etoolbox` could help me on that, but all my attempts of iterating through two lists were unsuccessful. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I need enlightment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be more elegant ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareListParser*{\dothedance}{,}

\newcommand{\saysomething}[2]{#1~#2\par}
\newcommand{\sayitto}[1]{%
  \dothedance{\saysomething{#1}}{Ann, Mary, Kate}
}


\begin{document}
\dothedance{%
\sayitto
}{Hello, Howdy}
\end{document}
```

produces:

```
Hello Ann
Hello Mary
Hello Kate
Howdy Ann
Howdy Mary
Howdy Kate
```

(In response to comment) To make it so that both lists can be specified at call-time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareListParser*{\dothedance}{,}
\DeclareListParser*{\dotheotherdance}{,}

\newcommand{\saysomething}[2]{#1~#2\par}
\newcommand{\sayitto}[1]{%
  \dothedance{\saysomething{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\dothetwostep}[3]{%
  \def\partner##1{%
    \dothedance{#1{##1}}{#3}%
  }
  \dothedance{\partner}{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\dothetwostep{\saysomething}{Hello, Howdy}{Ann, Mary, Kate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a very smart approach, Andrew! Unfortunately, for my particular case, both lists tend to be mutable throughout the document. If one of my lists were immutable, then I had no doubt on using your approach, it's a very concise code! =)

Comment: @Paulo: _That's_ easily solved.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, Andrew! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 5):

Why not :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\saysomething}[2]{ 
  \foreach \w in #1{%
  \foreach \n in #2{%
     \w~\n \par}}}  

\begin{document}
\def\Lone{ Hello, Howdy}
\def\Ltwo{ Ann, Mary, Kate}
\saysomething{\Lone}{\Ltwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, pretty impressive code! Thanks a lot for this alternative solution using `pgffor`, I was unaware of! Right now I need to stick with the `etoolbox` package because it's a collaborative document, but for the next documents, I'll give `pgffor` a try!

Comment: I second the recommendation to use `\foreach` here.

Comment: I prefer this one.

Answer (score 3):

This is another solution using `etoolbox` to follow Paulo Cereda's origin idea (direct nested loop).

And I add a `\directprodM` to allow the csv lists to be macro names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% #1 is a function
% #2 and #3 are literal csv lists
\newcommand\directprod[3]{%
  \renewcommand\do[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\do[1]{%
      #1{##1}{####1}}% awful, indeed
    \docsvlist{#3}%
    \endgroup}%
  \docsvlist{#2}}

% #2 and #3 are macros
\newcommand\directprodM[3]{%
  \edef\next{\noexpand\directprod\noexpand#1{#2}{#3}}%
  \next}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\saysomething[2]{#1~#2\par}

\directprod\saysomething{Hello, Howdy}{Ann, Mary, Kate}

or using macros for lists:
\newcommand\listA{Hello, Howdy}
\newcommand\listB{Ann, Mary, Kate}
\directprodM\saysomething\listA\listB

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\directprod` here is neither shorter nor simpler than @Andrew's definition. It just show how to nest macro definitions correctly. And supply a `\directprodM` to complete Andrew's solution.

Comment: Fantastic, Leo. I was struggling with those nested definitions and you made them clearer! Thanks!